# No results from Zend tablegateway using PDO with dblib driver

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, pdo, zend-framework2

Hopefully someone can make me look very silly. This problem is holding me up. I have been developing a web application on a local WAMP stack. I have been using the sqlsrv PDO driver and everything works wonderfully. I published my application to an Ubuntu 10.04 server that is using the PDO dblib driver. The majority of the site works but I have a query that will return only one record if the resultset is buffered. If it is not buffered no results appear. If I run the query with a PDO it works. If I query with a Zend TableGateway the results are not there. Any thoughts? The first image is the working display of the records and the second is the problem with a \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump().

[image: Working display]

[image: Not working display with a \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump()]

Update: I determined the issue is that I am querying the table in the controller and sending it to the view, but in the view I have a view helper hitting the same table. It would seem that the dblib driver is not handling asyncronous calls appropriately and the view helper is cutting off the controller's query. Any thoughts on a DB/Server config fix? If not I guess I get to re-code the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FreeTDS driver in use is not thread safe. To fix, each returned resultSet is immediately fed into a local array:

```
$resultSet = $this -> tableGateway -> selectWith ( $select );

$results = array();

foreach($resultSet as $r)
{
    $results[] = $r;
}

return $results;
```

This prevents database connections from interfering with each other.